# How to limit the number of nested documents shown in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nested, document

I have array of parent documents consisting of nested documents ranging between 20 to 500. How can I limit the number of nested documents shown for each parent document.

below is the structure of my Document and nested document.

```
[{
        id
        title
        users: [{
                user_id: 1,
                timestamp: 2354218,
                field3: 4
            }, {
                user_id: 1,
                timestamp: 2354218,
                field3: 4
            }, {
                user_id: 1,
                timestamp: 2354218,
                field3: 4
            },
            ...
        ]

    }, {

    },
    ...
]
```

**I want to limit the number of users shown for each parent document. how to?**

## My Query

```
db.movies.aggregate(
[{$match: {
    "movie_title":  "Toy Story (1995)"}
  },{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "users.user_id",
        foreignField: "users.id",
        as: "users"
    }
},
{$project: {

        movie_title: "$movie_title",
        users: { $slice: [ "$users", 1 ] }
    }}
]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below query. Use `$slice` to get at most first `n` elements in nested documents array for each document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { title: 1, nUsers: { $slice: [ "$users", n ] } } ])
```

or Using regular query.

```
db.collection.find({}, { title: 1, nUsers: {$slice: n } })
```

Comment: I have shown the query I am using with $slice as you mentioned. but I dont seem to get it working

Comment: I hope you figured that out already.

Comment: How can I limit the number of fields I am showing in "users". like I have users zip_code, occupation, gender, age,... I want to show only zip_code and occupation.

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259243/mongodb-is-it-possible-to-limit-the-results-of-lookup-to-certain-fields-as-a/42259504#42259504