# Limiting sub documents in Mongo db not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection named  **Shops** :

```
{
    "ShopId" : 9999,
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "productId" : "1234",
            "productName" : "sambarpowder 500 gm",
            "productCategory" : "masala",
            "mrp" : "90",
        }, 
        {
            "productId" : "5678",
            "productName" : "sambarpowder 1000 gm",
            "productCategory" : "masala",
            "mrp" : "38 ",
        }
    ],
   },{....}--> There will be a list of shops
```

**Query**

My query to fetch products based on the search value is :

```
 model.Shops.aggregate(
       {$match:{"ShopId":9999}},{$unwind:"$products"},
       {$match:{"products.productName":new RegExp('sambar','i') }},
      { $group:{_id:null,productList:{$push:{"productId":"$products.productId","productName":"$products.productName","price":"$products.mrp"}}}},{$limit:1})
```

**Output**

```
    [{
    "_id": null,
    "productList": [
      {
        "productId": "1234",
        "productName": "sambarpowder 500 gm",
        "price": "90"
      },
      {
        "productId": "5678",
        "productName": "sambarpowder 1000 gm",
        "price": "38 "
      }
    ]
  }]
```

**Problem**

The problem here is that I written **limit:1** in the query but it is returning **2 products**. I don't know how to limit the subdocuments in this.

Comment: See if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258325/how-to-limit-the-number-of-nested-documents-shown-in-mongodb/42258382#42258382

Comment: Tried.. but not working..

Comment: i need both offset and limit option ..so i given 0 and 1 inside slice